# TFS 2010 Build - batch file 'access denied'

Tags: tfs, batch-file, build-process

Running TFS 2010

I am trying to do a proof of concept, having batch files run as part of the build process. I have an 'invokeProcess' in my build seqeunce which runs a batch file. When I run the build, it 'partially succeeds' and then shows an 'access denied' error on the batch file.

Thoughts? Honestly I'm not even sure how to diagnose what user it is trying to run under.

Comment: What is the batch file doing?

Comment: Just a proof of concept - creating a dummy text file with some random text

Comment: How about changing the batch file to do nothing at all?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I thought you were crazy at first... and then I realized what it was doing. Using the suggestion from Jeremy in one of the answers below, I filtered everything out of procmon except for ACCESS DENIED... and I realized that it wasnt the batch file that it didnt have access to, but the c/system32/test1.txt that I was trying to create. I thought it would have created it in the local folder, but then I realized that it was ... local to the location of cmd.exe :) Once I changed the .bat file to just EXIT, it worked fine. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your build server different than your TFS server?  In our environment, our build server runs all the windows services that execute the builds.  Those builds are executed under the context of the user id that the build service is configured to start with.

To execute a batch file, you not only need to give permissions to the batch file itself, but you also need to grant rights to the cmd.exe file (since this will execute a new command line process) as well as any executables your batch file may call.

Try running procmon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and execute your build again - it will show you exactly what files the system is denying access to.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - Our build server is different than our TFS server, yes. I'll download procmon now and see what information I can come up with.

Comment: Good luck - FYI procmon generates a lot of data.  You'll have to mess with the filter or the find functions to get what you are looking for.  But I guarantee it's in there.  When you find it, it will be awesome.

Comment: Yes, I see that ha. I found a line that is relevant though - says that when running my batch file (operation DeviceIOControl_, the result is INVALID PARAMETER .. which makes it sound like a parameter that I'm passing to the batch file is wrong. The exact error message in TFS is: cmd.exe  /c C:\...\testBatch.bat , then Access is denied. The batch file itself is only: ECHO Your text goes here >test1.txt
exit ... so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Not sure that INVALID PARAMETER is really your problem.  If you are getting an access denied error, you should see "ACCESS DENIED" in the result column somewhere.  Try a filter where Result is "ACCESS DENIED" and see if that gives you something more useful.  You could also try a find on the string "testBatch.bat" and that will put you in the right neighborhood of where the failure occured.

Comment: thank you for leading me in the right direction. filtering for ACCESS DENIED led me to the problem being the test1.txt file instead of the batch file itself. See my comment to John on the answer above for the full details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the service account that is the identity for the build service has access to the batch location? You can find the service account in the TFS Administration Console (available on your TFS Server)

Comment: I have, and I found the solution a few minutes ago (see comments above), but I also just wanted to say thanks, considering it was your blog posts that even got me this far!